# How can I run a user script before any inline scripts run on a webpage?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I want to make a greasemonkey type script for firefox that runs before the scripts on the page.  Greasemonkey scripts run after scripts on the page, so that won't work.  The reason I need this is because I want to edit one of the scripts on the page.  Specifically, I want to delete a script that forces the page to load inside a frame since having the page inside a frame breaks F5 (Pressing F5 makes the page jump back to the front page instead of reloading the current page).  Also, I don't want to load the page through a proxy with AJAX and switching to chrome/opera is not an option either.  I was thinking maybe the Jetpack add-on would work but it seems to only have the same event that greasemonkey uses, DOMContentLoaded.  Any ideas?

Comment: **IF** Opera was an option, than you could have simply renamed your `*.user.js` file to `*.js` and it would run before any content had even started loading.

Comment: I know, but I don't use opera as my browser.  Since I've highly customized firefox, switching and still having everything the way I want it would probably be impossible.  Installing and using another browser for just 1 site seems a little silly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[edit 2013] Use the [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) module of the Add-on SDK with `contentScriptWhen` = `start`.

---

older:
Right, only newer Firefox builds (currently 3.7 nighlies, may later be added to 3.6.x) have support for running custom scripts before content-specified scripts. I [wrote a prototype Jetpack-SDK module](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-jetpack/browse_thread/thread/9deffcc11fa00ea) to take advantage of the new notification.

Is it a <script src> or an inline script? In the former case it can be blocked with a content policy (something adblock-like).

Comment: Interesting.  I'll see if I can figure out how to get it to work.  The script is an inline script.

Comment: Could you add a reference to an example for doing what @Telanor is asking?